# Is there an efficient way to find the creation dates for a list of articles?

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Given a list of article names, is there an efficient way to get the creation dates for all of them?

I know I can find the creation date of a single article by requesting the first revision:

```
{
    "action": "query",
    "format": "json",
    "prop": "revisions",
    "titles": "Wikipedia",
    "rvlimit": "1",
    "rvprop": "timestamp",
    "rvdir": "newer"
}
```

But this doesn't work with multiple `titles` and I would prefer not having to make one request per article if possible. Is there another approach that works with multiple titles?

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=User%3ARillke|Main%20page&rvprop=timestamp returns creation timestamps for `User:Rillke` and `Main page`. Maybe you would like to answer your own question?

Comment: You could use _generators_, if these titles have something in common: https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&rvprop=timestamp&generator=links&titles=Main%20Page